# play-clj tutorial dependency on unretrievable file

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen, lighttable, play-clj

I've tried following the steps of the [play-clj tutorial](https://github.com/oakes/play-clj/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md). I can't seem to run anything in my light table REPL because I can't retrieve files from Maven and clojars.org/repo/ . I'm using Leiningen as my package manager.

This is the error message I get:

Could not transfer artifact net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:jar:natives-windows:2.0.5 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): GET request of: net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar from central failed

So I tried to manually downloading the file myself by looking through Maven's website.
The file seems to be down. What are my best solutions to get this tutorial working?

EDIT 2: The file is now up. Took a few days.

Comment: I can see the file on maven central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/ are you trying it behind the proxy (e.g. at work)? I just did `lein new play-clj hello-world`, and it worked fine.